# Are there any UX problems with date pickers?

Tags: web-app, dates, datetimepicker

I’m adding a date picker for **delivery date selection** on a website. I recall developers mentioning that there are issues with date pickers.

Is there anything inherently wrong with date pickers UX-wise?

Comment: As with most things; it depends how they've been built. There are good ones and there are terrible ones.

Comment: There are ok ones, and then there are the rest, all varying degrees of terrible. Yet to see a good one.

Comment: When receiving information on any UX glitch important to get to specifics e.g. (1) problem definition - preferably with [Nielsen] heuristic affected (2) path to re-create problem (3) user persona affected.
Because *many perceived problems don't stack up in real world  situations.*

Comment: http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/ is quite a good one as you have 100% control over the styles and a pretty good control over the structure and functionality too. This way at least you can design it exactly the way you want.

Comment: Can the user just type in the date that is usually the quickest and if the picker fails to allow this then it is a real reason for me at least not to use the site.

Comment: @Novocaine That's good? I can't see any way to pick a date from those demos. Nor is there a text-entry version. And it doesn't seem to work with keyboard. Seems like style over substance to me.

Comment: Are all or almost all expected delivery dates within the next _n_ days where, say, _n_ ≤ 5 or 30? It’s a very different use case from entering a birthday, calendar event or expiration date. It’s more similar to booking a one-way train ticket.

Answer (score 1):

The jQueryUI datepicker allows the user to enter the date themselves, offers a popup calendar, and a "mask" (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy)

Questions to consider:

1. **International audience of your site** - for some weird reason, North American dates are written mm/dd/yyyy (most significant unit first?) and British dates are written dd/mm/yyyy (smallest unit first). Geeky dates are written yyyy/mm/dd (largest unit first). Pick one of these and stick to it, depending on the target audience (or detect locale and provide the regional preference).
2. **when entering date of birth,** you need an easy way to go back through the years - so don't use a calendar popup for this. Use three separate fields (dd, mmmm, and yyyy, and make the default setting of the yyyy field at least 18 years ago).
3. **flight/train/bus journeys** - most sites where you can book a flight or a train ticket allow you to add a return journey - if this is applicable to your site, you need two popups - and some popups display the next two months to pick your travel time in.
4. **Booking accommodation** - you need to be able to pick a range of days on the same calendar, e.g. staying in a hotel for 4 nights. (Have a look at AirBnB which has a nice date range picker.)

Comment: Date format confusion is usually best avoided by using (abbreviated) names for months, at least on a single-language site.